# Make highcharts display the tooltip of the previous point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way in Highcharts to cause the tooltip to be displayed not by the closest point to the mouse but always by the point to the left?
e.g in the picture below, I want that if the mouse is hovering the red area the tooltip that would be displayed is the tooltip of the point above May:
[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe with some coding. Not "as it is".

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far I was looking for a setting for this thing.. Couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tooltip Positioner](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner) which allows you to define your own positioning function.

Comment: Tooltip positioner only sets the position of the tooltip itself. The question is more about the trigger point to display the tooltip.

Comment: Unfortunatley this option is not supported, so you need to catch event on svg element and then show/hide your own div which will be "tooltip"