# Make Highcharts tooltip switch to the next point on the point itself

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

*There is an old question about the same functionality needed: [Make highcharts display the tooltip of the previous point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384619/make-highcharts-display-the-tooltip-of-the-previous-point). 
I just will try to see if maybe a new feature became available during these years.*

Question:

By default, tooltip will show the data of the closest point:

[image]

How to make it show all the time the point on the left until it reaches the next point?
[image]

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nsf0203g/12/

Its code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: {
            followPointer: true,
            shared: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1,
            crosshair: {enabled: true, snap: false, width: 3, color: '#ccc'}
        },
        series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2] }, {data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9] }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Is enabled `followPointer` your requirement?

Comment: It can be enabled, but the requirement is different. It concerns the highlighted point, not the positioning of the tooltip.

Comment: It seems that the last comment under the question you referred is still valid - this behavior is not supported by Highcharts.